# Database-based session classes/libraries without session_set_save_handler()

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-set-save-handler

I'm currently in the process of writing a PHP 'plug-in' that tracks sessions across unique domains. In order to do this, I've figured the best way to handle 'sessions' across different domains is to write my own Session class/library.

I've considered using `session_set_save_handler()` which is normally an excellent way of doing this. However, I'm concerned that many of the web applications that this PHP plug-in will be installed on may already have their own usage of `session_start()` and PHP sessions and I suspect it's likely that `session_set_save_handler()` may break a few things - so I'm reluctant to use that.

Before I go about rewriting my own MySQL PDO-database session library, I'm wondering if there's anything like this already out there so I don't go about reinventing the wheel so to speak? I've had a quick look on Google and I can only see ones that use `session_set_save_handler()` which is a no-no as I mentioned.

Here's a few that I've found already that I've ruled out:

**PHP-MySQL-Session-Handler**
https://github.com/sprain/PHP-MySQL-Session-Handler

*Rejected because it uses `session_set_save_handler(..)` and hence will force the rest of the web application to save sessions to MySQL in the same way (which I don't want for the reasons outlined above.)*

**Zebra Session**
https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Session

*This looked promising but rejected because it also uses `session_set_save_handler(..)`*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without using `session_set_save_handler` what I'm aware of. Session are handy, but getting there can a lot of pulled hair and wth-moments. `session_set_save_handler` removes a lot of the hair pulling and flip-the-table tantrum.

Are you really **really** sure you need a your custom session library? Rewriting one from scratch when there is existing functionality sounds very much inventing the wheel again.

Comment: Accepted as best answer because writing a database-based session class without `session_set_save_handler` is most definitely NOT for the faint of heart. Thanks ztripez.

Comment: I'd like to know what session_set_save_handler does, that cannot be handled in the provided methods for a custom DB handler?
So far I know about: a) generate session id - can be done with base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv().    b) garbage collection (delete old sessions), Should be easy enough to call a clean up function with a certain probability. .  c) commit session when script ends. - we can probably use register_shutdown_function or ensure a commit is run when the script ends (even when there are exceptions).  Any others?